# How to align left/right some \blocks in page

Tags: pdftex

I have some trouble when i try to align justify my blocks.

Here is an image with my problem
[image]

As you can see distance from right is bigger then left and i can't make this blocks to be stored in the middle of the page.
I don't know if i need to configure the document or the blocks. Here is the code that creates the blocks:

```
    \newenvironment{blocks}
{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \setlength\fboxrule{0.1pt}%
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
    \newcommand{\newblocks}{\par\nointerlineskip}%
}
{\par}
\newcommand{\Block}[4]{%
    \fbox{%
        \begin{minipage}[c][\dimexpr#1\textheight-2\fboxrule][t]{\dimexpr#2\textwidth-2\fboxrule}
            #3\par #4
        \end{minipage}%
    }%
    \ignorespaces
}
```

And for document i have setup only this

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}
```

Is there a way to align this blocks justify? Thanks

Comment: You use the `article` option `twoside`. In `twoside` documents the outer margin is bigger than the inner margin because the inner margins of the left and right page will be next to another and appear like one margin. So for double-sided documents you should not change this, for single sided documents you just have to delete `twoside`.

Comment: Thank you so much @MarcelKrüger. That was the problem. I have so many things to learn about laTeX. Thanks again.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You use the `article` option `twoside`. This is intended for double-sided books: If the book is open, the left page is located directly next to the right page, so the right margin of the left page and the left margin of the right page appear like one big margin. If all the margins have the same size, this inner margin is two wide, because it really consists of two margins. So `article` reduces the inner margins to half the size, such that together theses margins appear normal.

While this looks great for double-sided documents, on single-sided documents the margins look odd. To avoid this, you have to communicate to the document class that your document is single-sided: Instead of `twoside`, you have to use the `oneside` option.

For `article` `oneside` is the default, so you can simply delete the `twoside` which results in

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
```

Independent from this you might want to take a look at the [KOMA-Script](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) replacement for the `article` class, `scrartcl`. The margins of this class look better on A4 paper and it has excellent documentation, which also explains all the details of the margins for `oneside` and `twoside` documents.